# python win32com : Change Excel formula without inputing value yourself

Tags: python, python-2.7, excel-2007, win32com

Is there a way to change a formula without inputing the new value yourself?
Example:

```
Données!$EX$68:$IN$68
```

should become

```
Données!$EY$68:$IN$68
```

I don't want to calculate myself `EY` comes after `EX`, since it can go up to 4 letter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use R1C1 formatting to do this:

```
Row1 = 1
Column1 = 2
Row2 = 10
Column = 2

Formula = "=sum(r%(first)sc%(second)s:r%(third)sc%(fourth)s)" % {'first':Row1, 
                                                                 'second':Column1, 
                                                                 'third':Row2, 
                                                                 'fourth':Column}
xl.Cells(1,1).FormulaR1C1 = Formula
```

Makes the formula: `=SUM($B$1:$B$10)` in cell A1. There's lots of neat things you can do with R1C1 formatting in excel, like using [] to denote offsets.  Makes writing formulas from python a bit less painful. Hope this helps!